# Unpinning accepted answer from top of list of answers on GIS SE

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

As of today, [Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers) has been implemented for Stack Overflow.

Would we like to see the same to be done for GIS SE?

---

This discussion feeds into [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914/215590) to [Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568) where our preference is currently recorded as **Unpin**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, please unpin the accepted answer.  The answer accepted by the original poster is not always the best answer according to other users.

Unpinning will result in the answer that the majority believe is best will rise to the top, but the original poster's accepted answer will still be clearly visible as the one with the big green tick.

Comment: agreed, its a subtle change and probably will affect a small number of posts, but the ones that it does it will impact positively. So im ok with it.

Comment: Agree, as long as this answer is fullfilled: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369569/454427

Comment: Could be nice to have a switch button close to the question: "Move accepted answer to top / Move most voted answer to top".

Comment: @swiss_knight if you’d like an alternative answer for the GIS community to vote on feel free to add it to this question.